# Use variable number of output while assigning to varargout

Tags: matlab

I'm making a generic subsref for my classA, which has an attribute attrA that is a classB instance.
So far, it's working, it lets me do things like

```
x = objA.attr1.methB(),
```

which was what I was trying to do to do in the first place.

```
function this = Class1(varargin)
    this.attrA = ClassB()
    this = class(this,'ClassA')

function this = ClassB()
    this.AttrB1 = 'valueB1'
    this.AttrB2 = 'valueB2'

function out = methB
    out = this.AttrB2
```

The problem I stumbled upon is this:
when the call to a method is executed in my subsref, I do it like this (detecting that it's a method etc is done before):

```
methName = index(1).subs;                    
args = index(2).subs;
if iscell(args)                    
    varargout = {feval(methName,this,args{:})};            
else
    varargout = {feval(methName,this,args)};
end %end if iscell
```

The problem is that when the methName method supports variable number of outputs, this varargout is not equivalent to [x,y,...] (the number of outputs should be assigned in the call to subsref, so methName always returns a single output, which is not always what I want (almost, but not always).

How would I let methName know how many outputs I want? (I don't want to have to pass N as a parameter).

I'm thinking something like creating a string `str='[out1,out2,out3...]'` 
and then doing something like

```
eval([ 
str ...
'= {feval(methName,this,args{:})};'...
])
```

But I keep thinking there must be a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: How about `[output{1:n}] = {feval(methName,this,args{:})};` with `n` being the number of outputs you expect?

Comment: I hope I'm not the only one with a small smirk behind the screen when reading `methName`. Thanks for this post, it was helpful to me. Solution should be marked

Answer (score 4):

If the number of outputs you expect is dependent on the output arguments requested from your subsref, you can simply use `nargout` like this:

```
[varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(methName,this,args{:});
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked, but I needed to add a little something for single outputs:

```
if iscell(args)
    [argout{:}] = feval(methName,this,args{:});            
else
    [argout{:}]= {feval(methName,this,args)};
end %end if iscell`
if isSingleCell(argout) && iscell(argout{1})`
    v = argout{1};
    argout{1}=v{1};
end
```

I'm not sure, but it may be that the last bit was only necessary to fix something else ( I had to fix a lot of other things to make this work). I'll get back to it when I finish what I was trying to do with this class